# If range A value not equal to any of range D value, add range A value to range D

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to ask whats the logic that I should use in order to search for Range A value in Range D. If Range A value is not equal to any of Range D, would like to add it under Range D.

[image]

I had came out with this code. However for the Range1, is it possible to set to last row in range A which contain value?

```
Sub find()

Dim range1 As Range
Set range1 = Range("A1:A9")
Dim range2 As Range
Set range2 = Range("D:D")
Dim rgvalue1 As Variant
Dim rgvalue2 As Variant
Dim rgfound As Variant

For Each rgvalue1 In range1

    Set rgfound = range2.find(rgvalue1)

    If rgfound Is Nothing Then
    Range("D1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = rgvalue1

    End If

Next rgvalue1


Dim i As Integer
i = 2

Do Until Cells(i, 4) = ""


 Cells(i, 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(C[-3],MATCH(RC[-1],C[-4],0),0)"
 i = i + 1

 Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Because this is no free code writing service: ① Have a look at the [WorksheetFunction.VLookup Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-vlookup-method-excel) ② Do some research, start on your own, and if you have a **specific** issue with your code come back here show your code and tell where you got errors and which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use a name for your procedure that is already used by VBA. You name your procedure `Sub find()` but `find` is already the name of a VBA method. This will soon or later cause strange issues and is a very bad practice.

Instead use meaningful names like `Sub FindMissingProductsAndCopyThem()`.

I suggest the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FindMissingProductsAndCopyThem()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'define which worksheet

    Dim lRowSource As Long
    lRowSource = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find last row in column A

    Dim lRowDestination As Long
    lRowDestination = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row 'find last row in column D

    Dim FoundRow As Long

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 2 To lRowSource 'loop throug data of column A
        FoundRow = 0 'initialize/reset
        On Error Resume Next 'next line throws an error if not matched, catch that error
        'try to find/match the data of column A in column D
        FoundRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(iRow, "A"), ws.Columns("D"), 0)
        On Error GoTo 0 're-activate error reporting

        'if Match threw an error, then FoundRow is still 0

        If FoundRow = 0 Then 'product was not found, so add it
            lRowDestination = lRowDestination + 1
            ws.Cells(lRowDestination, "D").Value = ws.Cells(iRow, "A")
        End If
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice and clear explaination. Now I learnt can loop using On Error. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The logic would be:

Set a pointer to first cell in A

Start Loop

Find the value of pointer in D. (either using WorksheetFunction.MATCH or FIND)

If not found then

Find Next Blank Row in D

Copy pointer value to that row, column D

(optionally, blank cell in A)

Advance pointer to next cell

If you've reached the last cell in A then stop, else loop back to start of loop

Now you can translate that to VBA code

Comment: thank you for your advice. However the code i tried out took longer time to run all the lines. Can I improve in some  way?